# Determining why IIS 6.0 Rapid-Fail Protection occurred

Tags: iis, asp.net

We had an IIS 6.0 Rapid-Fail Protection occur during testing of our ASP.NET web application. This issue appeared to be introduced by code that I wrote.

How do we determine what caused it? There is nothing interesting showing up through ASP.NET health monitoring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Event Viewer is the first place to look, but may not have the answer.  The next thing to check are the IIS logs.  You may be able to find patterns in usage prior to the failure.

If you can't find answers with either of those then try out Debug Diag.  It's a bit more work to find the answer, but likely that you'll be able to with a big of digging.